# kubectl failed to ensure lease exists error

Tags: kubernetes, fedora

I'm trying to deploy an at home k8s node to learn on and deploy some actual services I rely on to. I have taken the following steps:

1. Install Fedora Server 39
2. Follow the directions at `https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-kubernetes/` to deploy the k8s cluster, with the exception of using `containerd` instead of `CRI-O`, and using Canal instead of Flannel using the deployment yaml at `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.27.0/manifests/canal.yaml`

I also ran all command printed by kubeadm after the init command completes to set up my profile for kubectl. I immediately started to get an issue where sometimes `kubectl` commands would run, and sometimes I'd get a `Service Unreachable on 6443` error. Once I started digging I found the following errors in the kubelet logs:

```
I0129 10:39:19.409618    1170 kubelet_node_status.go:70] "Attempting to register node" node="localhost"
E0129 10:39:19.411296    1170 kubelet_node_status.go:92] "Unable to register node with API server" err="nodes \"localhost\" is forbidden: node \"localhost.localdomain\" is not allowed to modify node \"localhost\"" node="localhost"
E0129 10:39:21.998836    1170 eviction_manager.go:262] "Eviction manager: failed to get summary stats" err="failed to get node info: node \"localhost\" not found"
E0129 10:39:26.204801    1170 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="leases.coordination.k8s.io \"localhost\" is forbidden: User \"system:node:localhost.localdomain\" cannot get resource \"leases\" in API group \"coordination.k8s.io\" in the namespace \"kube-node-lease\": can only access node lease with the same name as the requesting node" interval="7s"
```

I've tried the following:

1. Re-disabling firewalld
2. Re-disabling swap with `swapoff --all`
3. Change SELinux Policy from `ENFORCE` to `PERMISSIVE`
4. Removing all `localdomain` references in `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`
5. Changing hostname with `hostnamectl hostname localhost.localdomain`
6. Restarting the server

The issue persists. All solutions I find online seem to boil down to either option (1) or option (2) from above, to no avail. Any ideas on what I could try next?

Extra info:

Output from `kubectl get nodes`:

```
NAME                    STATUS     ROLES           AGE   VERSION
localhost.localdomain   NotReady   control-plane   12h   v1.27.10
```

Output from `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-867bf4f5b5-kz2r9        0/1     Pending   0             121m
kube-system   canal-pw6j2                                     0/2     Pending   0             121m
kube-system   coredns-5d78c9869d-rvmzw                        0/1     Pending   0             12h
kube-system   coredns-5d78c9869d-zn9lx                        0/1     Pending   0             12h
kube-system   etcd-localhost.localdomain                      1/1     Running   5 (12h ago)   12h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-localhost.localdomain            0/1     Running   8 (12h ago)   12h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-localhost.localdomain   1/1     Running   7 (12h ago)   12h
kube-system   kube-proxy-mrsvp                                0/1     Unknown   6             12h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-localhost.localdomain            1/1     Running   6 (12h ago)   12h
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like this has to do with how kubelet and the control plane handles permissions using the hostname of the device. When `dnf` installs `kubernetes-kubeadm`, the default configuration file for kubelete specified localhost.localdomain, no mater what the domain name of the server itself actually is. So after installing `kubernetes-kubeadm` but before running `kubeadm init`, you need to replace the config file's references to the hostname with the servers actual hostname with

`sed --in-place=".old" "s/localhost.localdomain/$(hostname)/" /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`

Explaining the command:

1. `sed` is "stream editor" which is included with GNU tools for many linux distrobutions
2. `--in-place=".old"` copies the existing configuration file to a file with the same name ending in ".old" before modifying the file specified
3. `"s/localhost.localdomain/$(hostname)/"` replaces any instance of the string "localhost.localdomain" with the value returned by running `hostname`.
4. `./kubelet.conf` the configuration file to modify.

Hope this help others! Now off to other battles!